# OpenVPN: Only route a specific IP addresses through VPN?

Tags: ubuntu, routing, openvpn, centos7

I have installed OpenVPN with certificates using this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7 and i use static ip adress with ccd directory.

How can I configure the OpenVPN client to ONLY route traffic through the VPN that is destined for a single, specific IP address?

Example:

- https://www.google.com/ -> Direct access without VPN
- https://intranet/ -> Connect via VPN (10.8.0.x)

The server is CentOS 7 and the client is Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Add to the server config:

```
push route 10.8.0.x 255.255.255.255
```

Comment: Does not work, add line to end of server.conf, reboot server and client servce but whatismyip.com says the ip adress is ip of vpn server.

Comment: Do you use redirect-gateway in your configs? As mentioned in the article you sent: "We need to uncomment the push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" line, which tells the client to redirect all traffic through our OpenVPN."

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

Comment: Works fine, i need "route-nopull" before push route and it in client config no server config.

Comment: @e-info128 Could you be more specific of what you put in the client config?